# How to retrieve products from Shopify API using CLI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify

Run the Shopify CLI but still is very difficult to do anything.

Would like to retrieve 10 articles from Shopify between those id's but I am getting an error that URLSearchParams is not recognized.
Pretty sure that is something really easy.

The full code below is where I am at the moment.

index.js

```html
import { Heading, Page } from "@shopify/polaris";

const Index = () => (
  <Page
    title='Trustpilot Aggreggation Uploader'
    primaryAction={{
      content: 'Update Metafields',
      onAction: () =>
      {
          console.log('appliying products');

          var limit = 10;
          var sinceId = '0,921728736';

          const product = async (limit, sinceId) => {
              const res = await fetch(
                "/products?" +
                  new URLSearchParams({
                    limit,
                    since_id: sinceId,
                  })
              );
              return await res.json();
            };
      }
    }}
  />
);

export default Index;
```

server.js

```html
import "@babel/polyfill";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import "isomorphic-fetch";
import createShopifyAuth, { verifyRequest } from "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth";
import Shopify, { ApiVersion } from "@shopify/shopify-api";
import Koa from "koa";
import next from "next";
import Router from "koa-router";

dotenv.config();
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 8081;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({
  dev,
});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  API_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
  API_SECRET_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
  SCOPES: process.env.SCOPES.split(","),
  HOST_NAME: process.env.HOST.replace(/https:\/\//, ""),
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.October20,
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: true,
  // This should be replaced with your preferred storage strategy
  SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.MemorySessionStorage(),
});

// Storing the currently active shops in memory will force them to re-login when your server restarts. You should
// persist this object in your app.
const ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS = {};

app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = new Koa();
  const router = new Router();
  server.keys = [Shopify.Context.API_SECRET_KEY];
  server.use(
    createShopifyAuth({
      async afterAuth(ctx) {
        // Access token and shop available in ctx.state.shopify
        const { shop, accessToken, scope } = ctx.state.shopify;
        ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] = scope;

        const response = await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.register({
          shop,
          accessToken,
          path: "/webhooks",
          topic: "APP_UNINSTALLED",
          webhookHandler: async (topic, shop, body) =>
            delete ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop],
        });

        if (!response.success) {
          console.log(
            `Failed to register APP_UNINSTALLED webhook: ${response.result}`
          );
        }

        // Redirect to app with shop parameter upon auth
        ctx.redirect(`/?shop=${shop}`);
      },
    })
  );

  const handleRequest = async (ctx) => {
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
    ctx.respond = false;
    ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
  };

  router.get("/", async (ctx) => {
    const shop = ctx.query.shop;

    // This shop hasn't been seen yet, go through OAuth to create a session
    if (ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] === undefined) {
      ctx.redirect(`/auth?shop=${shop}`);
    } else {
      await handleRequest(ctx);
    }
  });

   router.get("/products", async (ctx) => {
     try {
       const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;
              const res = await fetch(        'https://${SHOPIFY_API_KEY}:${accessToken}@${shop}/admin/api/2020-10/products.json?${new URLSearchParams(
           ctx.request.query
         )}'
       );
       ctx.body = await res.json();
       ctx.status = 200;
   } catch (error) {
     console.log('Failed to process products: ${error}');
   }
   });

  router.post(
    "/graphql",
    verifyRequest({ returnHeader: true }),
    async (ctx, next) => {
      await Shopify.Utils.graphqlProxy(ctx.req, ctx.res);
    }
  );

  router.get("(/_next/static/.*)", handleRequest); // Static content is clear
  router.get("/_next/webpack-hmr", handleRequest); // Webpack content is clear
  router.get("(.*)", verifyRequest(), handleRequest); // Everything else must have sessions

  server.use(router.allowedMethods());
  server.use(router.routes());
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please beware that **URLSearchParams** class was added as a Global Object **only on Node v10**.
On older versions of Node you have to import it first:

```
import { URLSearchParams } from 'url';
global.URLSearchParams = URLSearchParams
```

Comment: Thanks Joao but I am using node version v10.16.3 .